# Fetch Email IDs of a google group to my android app

Tags: android, google-groups

I'm a student and working on my college's major project which requires email id(s) of a particular google group. Is it possible to fetch all email id(s) of a particular google group in my app?

Answer (score 0):

google groups has an API that you can hook into to get group members. tutorial here:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/android

they also have a pure web json api for getting group members as well
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members